# Customer Service Hub business process flow issue on Case entity

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-crm-365-v9, interactive-service-hub

I have been working with dynamics 365 v9.0 and I have been facing this issue on customer service hub application. In case entity, there is bpf called "phone to case process". In first stage there is one field called "Find Case". This field is displaying in browser view of case entity, but I am not able to see “Find Case” in customer service hub application.

I have also go through [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customer-service/customer-service-hub-user-guide-basics) site and under ”Business processes” title the field is displaying under bpf stage.
[image]

Below image is my environment’s image:

[image]

Does anybody help me for this issue?

Comment: Is this question about a programming issue? It appears to be about an issue you are having with *using* your CRM software, and not something where you've added custom code to it. Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @Makyen SO questions revolving around Dynamics (CRM, AX, etc) not only involves coding, but also Customizations & configurations.. Community needs full support.. thanks for understanding..

Comment: @ArunVinoth I can understand that, but how does *this* question related to programming? A CRM isn't, inherently, a programming issue. *This* question, on it's face, does not appear to be "unique to software development", thus the request for for more information.

Comment: @Makyen I agree, you have to bare with us till this happen: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345155

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It’s listed as a [known issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/admin/readme-9#customer-service-hub-app-on-dynamics-365-for-tablets-and-dynamics-365-for-phones) under section **Customer Service Hub app on Dynamics 365 for tablets and Dynamics 365 for phones**. But maybe it’s affecting wider.

> Phone to case process:
>   The Find Case option on the Identify stage isn't available for update for an existing case.